# Toggle select2 from different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

We have a select2 dropdown in a row (just a div) and we need to be able to click that entire row to trigger the dropdown. I have no problem showing it, but trying to hide it has become a problem, and I'm wondering if my logic is flawed somewhere. select2 AFAIK doesn't have a toggle method on the version we're on, so I have to manually use it's open and close methods. This is what I tried.

```
$('[data-variable-type=select]').on('click', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  var _dropdown = $(this).find('div.interface_dropdown');
  if( _dropdown.hasClass('select2-dropdown-open') ) {
    $(this).find('select.interface_dropdown').select2('close');
  }
  else {
    $(this).find('select.interface_dropdown').select2('open');
  }
});
```

This causes it to open properly, but when you click to close it, it closes on mousedown but reappears on mouseup.

Is there someway I can get it toggling properly?

Answer (score 1):

Will you post relevant HTML? It's hard to understand what you're doing without seeing content.

```
$('[data-variable-type=select]').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation();
    var _dropdown = $(this).find('div.interface_dropdown');
    if( _dropdown.hasClass('select2-dropdown-open') ) {
        _dropdown.removeClass('select2-dropdown-open');
        _dropdown.select2('close');
    } else {
       _dropdown.select2('open');
       _dropdown.addClass('select2-dropdown-open');
   }
});
```

It looks like you forgot to add/removethat class, maybe this will work better? Again, I'm kind of feeling around in the dark here without seeing your content.

Comment: I believe the 'open' and 'close' methods of select2 handle that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( _dropdown.hasClass('select2-dropdown-open') ) {
$(this).find('select.interface_dropdown').select2('close');
}
```

in later versions of select2 (3.3+ iirc) this will never get triggered because when opened select2 creates a transparent mask over the entire browser and listens to click events. when the mask is clicked currently opened select2 is closed. this was the only reliable way to close a select2 when the user is ready to do something else.

Comment: Thanks, we're upgrading our version now, I will let you know if we make any headway :)

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is:

```
$('select').data('select2').toggleDropdown()
```